# Why don't we consider the Gamow factor when configuring the cyclotron?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Most of the time, during a collision the repulsive force between the protons will beat the attractive force that binds the nucleus together and the whole thing is torn apart.

But very **occasionally**, the nuclear strong force wins out: the two nuclei fuse together and relax to a ground state, and a new element is born.

*This is the probability factor for two nuclear particles' chance of overcoming the Coulomb barrier in order to undergo nuclear reactions, say fusion for instance - why isn't this used?

$$P_g(E) = \exp \left( - \sqrt{E_g/ E} \right) \, .$$
Here is a link to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamow_factor

The problem is that for two nuclei to fuse, the electrostatic repulsion between 
their positive charges has to be overcome.

What this means is that the collision has to take place at very high energies. Typically, this involves firing a light element projectile at a heavy element target.

cutting-edge superheavy discovery uses calcium-48, an unusually neutron-rich projectile. One gram of calcium-48 costs **$200,000** (£160,000),

experiments running for weeks at a time only manage to produce very little quantities of elements like 115. with such powerful mathematical equations such as the Gamow factor, shouldn't we have perfected the cyclotron,

so that we can produce grams of a new element at a time, instead of one or two atoms a day?

Comment: I don't know about the Gamow factor, so I won't write an answer. But the main problem in synthesizing elements with large Z by fusion isn't Coulomb repulsion, it's the lack of neutrons, since the neutron : proton ratio of the reactant nuclei is much smaller than what the product nucleus requires.

Comment: The question is unclear. Why do you think the Coulomb barrier is not considered in heavy ion fusion experiments?

Answer (score 2):

The cyclotron is a particle accelerator, it means it makes a beam of particles with a given momentum/energy in the laboratory frame, and it can be used to study interactions. The experimenters decide what the want to study with the specific beam of charged particles.

The particles in the beam do not interact with each other,by construction, one wants a statistics to accumulate for the same energy/momentum interactions. If one goes to the center of mass of one of the beam particles, in an interval delta(t) they will be at rest with each other within experimental errors , by construction. Thus there is no use of a Gamow factor , since there are minimal interactions of the beam particles with each other.

If by "configuring the cyclotron" you mean designing an experiment with the cyclotron beam that will lead to a fusion reaction with a target, you should make that clearer. If you search the terms, you will find that such experiments [have been proposed](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/757040) . Maybe you would be interested to delve into [this publication.](http://www.nupecc.org/ecos/ECOS-Final.pdf)